# Scala Salat Deserialization: how to get a Map[String, Number]?

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah, salat

My database looks like

```
[
  {
    name: "domenic",
    records: {
      today: 5,
      yesterday: 1.5
    }
  },
  {
    name: "bob",
    records: { ... }
  }
]
```

When I try queries like

```
val result: Option[DBObject] = myCollection.findOne(
  MongoDBObject("name" -> "domenic")
  MongoDBObject("records" -> 1),
)

val records = result.get.getAs[BasicDBObject]("records").get
grater[Map[String, Number]].asObject(records)
```

it fails (at runtime!) with

```
GRATER GLITCH - unable to find or instantiate a grater using supplied path name

REASON: Class scala.collection.immutable.Map is an interface

Context: 'global'
Path from pickled Scala sig: 'scala.collection.immutable.Map'
```

I think I could make this work by creating a case class whose only field is a `Map[String, Number]` and then getting its property. Is that really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

`grater` doesn't take a collection as a type argument, only a case class or a trait/abstract class whose concrete representations are case classes.  Since you're just querying for a map, just extract the values you need out of the `DBObject` using `getAs[T]`.

`Number` may not be a supported type in Salat - I've certainly never tried it.  If you need `Number` you can write a custom transformer or send a pull request to add real support to Salat.

Comment: `Number` is the only way to work with JSON in my short experience, since otherwise it throws an exception whenever you have non-fractional numbers (e.g. `[45.4, 45.6, 45.8, 46, 46.2]`).

Comment: Can you show what the `getAs` code would look like?